# Amcharts Trendline stack behind

Tags: amcharts

I am using Trend line in amstockcharts. They are fine except that they always stack on top of other graphs. Is it possible to set it stack behind ?

Comment: No. There's currently no such feature available.

Comment: @Jerson did my answer help, or do you need another solution?

Comment: Yes it work ! Fantastic! It also work for stockChart by changing chart.panel[0].stockGraph[i].  However, what is the meaning of set.D.container ? where can i find more information on that ? thanks

Comment: The "D" object is an internal object for drawing of the chart. It contains for example the reference to the container (the svg). I think this is not officially documented, as it is only for internal purposes. See my updated answer for a simplified approach. (which actually uses set.D.container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG there is no z-Index like in HTML. The last appended element is drawn on top of the others. So while there is no AmCharts feature supporting your request, you could manually redraw all Graphs, so that they're on top of the Trendlines again.

To do this, use '[appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)' to reappend the element to the SVG.
Now do this everytime the chart is drawn. For this we need an Event Listener for '[drawn](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#drawn)' (called when resizing the chart) and one for '[zoomed](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#drawn)' (obvious i think).

This is the resulting code:

```
chart.addListener("zoomed", drawGraphsOnTop);
chart.addListener("drawn", drawGraphsOnTop);

function drawGraphsOnTop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; i++) {
        chart.graphs[i].set.D.container.appendChild(chart.graphs[i].set.node);
    }
}
```

I've also prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5ocyxe8/) for that.

**Edit:**
I found a better way to do this. (Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7houfk6h/))

```
function drawGraphsOnTop() {
    chart.graphsSet.toFront();
}
```

(Actually you could also do `chart.trendlinesSet.toBack()` which would fit to your question better, but then the Trendlines are even behind the grid)

**Explanation:**
The chart is consisting of multiple "sets". For each type of component there's a set (e.g. GraphsSet, AxesSet, CursorSet,...) and each individual component has its own set (e.g. graph.set).
You can call `.toFront()` or `.toBack()` for each to change their layer. Note, that for the individual set this only changes the layer **inside** the types' set. (It means you e.g. set one graph on top of all other graphs but not on top of all other chart elements, for this you must move the whole graphsset)

Comment: I tried and this works for AmSerialChart. However, AMStockCharts got a bit naughty that the graphs will go back again when browser window resized. There is no 'drawn' event for AMStockCharts. I fixed this by monitoring the windows resize event --> fire chart.validateNow() --> fire the 'rendered' event. http://jsfiddle.net/yanjar/h3fh4hLu Line 636-639

Comment: AmStockCharts does not have a `drawn` event because its somewhat like the container for multiple charts. The [`StockPanel`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel) element is inheritor of `AmSerialChart` and hence has the `drawn` event.